# $git log waits for me to write smth

Tags: git

I suppose this is a really stupid question and I'm sorry for this, but I don't know how to fix it and what I'm supposed to do.

I have never used a source control system, so I started reading Git's documentation. But I came this problem: when I execute `$ git log` it gives me "`:`" and it waits for me to do something but I don't know what and how to return back and be able to write a new command. It also says "No next tag (press RETURN) but I don't know how to press it :( Please help, because now the only way to continue is to close the bash after every $git log... And sorry once again for the stupid question.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Press <kbd>q</kbd>. You have entered a pager output (`less` or `more`) but with an empty text.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much! Is there a way to run git log without entering this pager output? :)

Comment: Yup, you can use `--no-pager`. Sorry for the delay in answering.

Comment: Note that the "--no-pager" has to come before the "log".

Comment: Thanks it work for me i press `q` it stop, well i write `git log bug-fix --oneline` command.

Answer (score 6):

Note: if you want to avoid the pager option, you can do a:

```
git --no-pager log
```

From the [git man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git.html):

```
--no-pager
```

> Do not pipe git output into a pager.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply!